# How to programmatically inject plugin hooks to a unittest module running pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

In my project, I have a class that derives from `unittest.TestCase` (let's call it `FooTestCase`). Multiple projects in my organization import this class and use it as a drop-in replacement for unittests.

We use pytest as the testing platform because it has nice code coverage and html report generation options.

In each project, we have a `conftest.py` in the project root that has the following hooks:

```
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
     # ...

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
     # ...

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_html(report, data):
     # ...

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
     # ...
```

This code is copy pasted between projects and essentially alters the output formatting of the HTML reports to utilize the information generated by the `FooTestCase`. Those functions are all hooks to the `pytest_html` plugin.

Can I make it so that simply importing, or if that's not possible, instantiating the `FooTestCase` automatically injects the above hooks into the pytest execution environment?

I have not found any examples that seem to do or explain this, as most focus on making pytest plugins meant to be used "pytest-side".

Comment: Hooks are registered before the test collection/execution, so you have to distribute the hooks if you want to reuse them. For example, you could move the hooks to the module that defines `FooTestCase`. You could then pass its name to `pytest`, e.g. `pytest -p foo.bar` to autoload the plugin hooks. Or you could declare plugin usage via `pytest_plugins = ["foo.bar"]` in the `conftest.py`. Or you can make your module installable and define a `pytest` `setuptools` entrypoint.

Comment: This was my understanding from reading docs as well. Are you saying it's impossible to do it otherwise or it's just not part of normal operating procedure?